# How can i disable iphone camera auto-flash function?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I want to disable camera flash.

How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: the question is a little vague, as far as i know you can just toggle it on or off, but then that's hardly a coding related issue... can you provide more detail?

Comment: The following code is made by me
I tried to turn off iphone camera flash.
But it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are setting your camera capture session with AV Foundation:

Tell the **AVCaptureDevice** to **lockForConfiguration**, then tell it to **setFlashMode**

Read the documentation since this is a very simple task.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188

**Edit**: What you are looking for is explicitly written under the "media capture" section from the link I posted.